# Mysterious appearance of \\tsclient\c in Windows Explorer

Tags: networking, hard-drive, security, firewall

I normally see this in Windows Explorer (under This PC) WHEN I am making an RDC connection to my home computer. But it disappears after I disconnect. I have not connected via RDC in weeks.

Today, after booting the PC, I am seeing this entry when logged into the Desktop. Unlike its usual location, it is showing up under Quick Access. Is this functioning as a recently-used location list? I want to be sure I don't have a security issue (especially since the RDC port is blocked by the firewall).

Comment: I don't think it would be Quick Access after several weeks. I connect to my home computer as well. Is there any chance you connected inadvertently and then (because of this) did not disconnect

Comment: Recently used items always show up in quick access by default. Just right click and remove it from your quick access list. The item itself is part of Remote Desktop when you enable the local devices and resources options to include one of your disk drives. It allows you to access a local drive from within the remote connection.